# Restricting callerID choices in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I have a very simple Twilio setup for my company as our phone system. I've one specific problem: at the moment, anyone can use any of the numbers that have been associated with the company on the site for calling out. So Bob might accidentally use Alice's number, and that's unfortunate.

How do I change that? I would like to be able to set it so that each non-administrator user can only use one phone number for calling out, specifically the number associated with their user or device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subaccounts:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts

Alternatively, enforce the extra Caller ID logic in your own application and refuse calls if they don't match the correct params.

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer I was hoping for, and will involve a good deal of grumbling work, but better than "not possible". :)